How can I use 16 bit data in HM?
I want to use the HM from this link https://vcgit.hhi.fraunhofer.de/jvet/HM/-/tree/master/ with 16-bit data.
However, it doesn't work.
so I changed RExt__HIGH_BIT_DEPTH_SUPPORT in the typedef.h file to 1.
After that, when I tried to rebuild, I started getting LNK1181 errors.
I also tried changing HIGH_BITDEPTH to ON in the CMakeLists.txt file, but the error persisted.
How can I solve this?
I appreciate your advice.
